# Docker Compose returns error about property devices when trying to enable GPU

Tags: docker

I am trying to run my docker image using docker-compose. I have created a docker image named *visual_detector_v3* and also created a docker-compose.yaml file to use it:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  VisualDetections:
    image: 'visual_detector_v3:latest'
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

which is basically composed of the example given in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gpu-support/).
The only differences are that I have removed `command` (which I did not needed), changed *test* to *VisualDetections* and added version.

```
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              count: 1
              capabilities: [gpu]
```

Anyway, when I tried to execute using:

```
$docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yaml visualdetections
```

> services.VisualDetections.deploy.resources.reservations Additional
> property devices is not allowed

which does not seem to be affected by the changes I have made but rather from reservations. So, can you provide any thought on this issue?

The machine I am trying to run it has 2 GPUs and runs Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

See the note here:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#devices

Apparently this option is ignored when deploying a Swarm stack...

There are other options for deploying GPU resources in a Swarm:

https://gist.github.com/RafaelWO/290b764e88933b0c0769b6d2394fcad2