# Docker Compose GPU Support: services.*.deploy.resources.reservations Additional property devices is not allowed

Tags: docker-compose, gpu, docker-swarm

Versions of Docker tooling:

```
Docker Compose version v2.6.0
Docker Engine Version 20.10.17 (client)
Docker Engine Version 20.10.17 (server)
```

I've got a compose file that starts a swarm with `networks` and `secrets`, so I'm using Docker Compose File Version 3.9.

One of my services is a GPU resource, so I added this based on [current docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#resources):

```
version: "3.9"

services:

  my-app:
    image: my-app:latest
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - capabilities: [gpu]
              count: all
    . . .
```

My IDE is complaining with "expected scalar value" indicating that it doesn't recognize the key or value of `capabilities` and `count` and when I run the command:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml my-stack
```

Docker throws an error:

```
services.prosit-app.deploy.resources.reservations Additional property devices is not allowed
```

Based on the versions of my Docker tools and the schema I'm using, this should all work (I think). What am  missing?

I've tried various file versions and I can get the IDE warning to go away but then Docker can't support the file version. I've tried with and without quotes `["gpu"]`, different options, etc, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was asked already (my bad) and the answer was missed by me and others:

[Docker Compose returns error about property devices when trying to enable GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029582/docker-compose-returns-error-about-property-devices-when-trying-to-enable-gpu/72691651#72691651)

Reference:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#devices

Comment: My IDE is complaining with "expected scalar value" as well. I have not used `docker stack deploy ` . Do you know why the IDE is complaining about that?

Comment: Not completely sure why the IDE inspection refers to the scalar value, but the Docker issue is that GPUs can't be enabled when using Swarms. It's possible that PyCharm has a minor bug in this inspection and/or it's not sync-ed with current Docker specs.